# Multiple inheritance, base class pointers and sizeof

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, sizeof

Take [the typical demonstration of how pointer values can change through casting](http://codepad.org/KgZk4o3W):

```
struct B1 { int x; };
struct B2 { int y; };
struct D  : B1, B2 { };

int main() {
   D d;
   cout << (B1*)&d << " " << (B2*)&d << " " << &d;
}

// Typical output:
// 0xbf814ab4 0xbf814ab8 0xbf814ab4
```

I got to thinking; that offset probably does not exist when `B1` has no members, so I checked and [it's true](http://codepad.org/8BZunQhs) (at least in this case; not sure how standards-guaranteed this behaviour is):

```
struct B1 { };
struct B2 { };
struct D  : B1, B2 { };

int main() {
   D d;
   cout << (B1*)&d << " " << (B2*)&d << " " << &d;
}

// Typical output:
// 0xbf6ad95b 0xbf6ad95b 0xbf6ad95b
```

But then, `sizeof(T)` cannot be `0`, so [`sizeof(B1)` is still `1`](http://codepad.org/pH0eZAQd).

It strikes me that this "discrepancy" may potentially cause serious error-prone code where a programmer assumes that `(char*)(B2*)&d - (char*)(B1*)&d == (ptrdiff_t)sizeof(B1)`.

Is my analysis accurate?

Comment: When a programmer makes an incorrect assumption, there will be errors in the code.  No further analysis necessary.

Comment: There's no "offset" when `B1` is empty due to empty base optimisation, I think. As it's an optimisation, I think a conforming compiler is not forced to do it.

Comment: @Darren: That would seem to violate the as-if rule.

Comment: @Tomalak: the *as-if* rule states that whatever the compiler does it must be *as-if* the program executed abiding the description in the standard. In this case, the standard defines that to be a valid behavior. Note that the only reason that `sizeof(B1)` is 1 is that no two objects must have the same address in memory. That is an artificial increase in memory to guarantee that behavior.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that's true. I know that MSVC does some funny things with EBO (it only does EBO with the first parent in the multiple inheritance case). Maybe someone can confirm exactly what the standard has to say...???

Comment: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=319 is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `B1` and `B2` objects are subobjects of `d`.  The `sizeof` operator gives information about the size of a complete object, not a subobject.

The Standard allows but does not require a base class subobject to occupy no memory.  So on another compliant implementation, you could find in your second example that the subobjects have different addresses after all.

> 1.8p5: Unless it is a bit-field, a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage.  Base class subobjects may have zero size.  An object of trivially copyable or standard-layout type shall occupy contiguous bytes of storage.
>
> 1.8p6: Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies.  Two distinct objects that are neither bit-fields nor base class subobjects of zero size shall have distinct addresses.

And the only "safe" uses of pointer arithmetic are:

- On pointers to elements of the same array
- The guarantee that the address of a subobject `y` of complete object `x` is between `&x` inclusive and `&x+1` exclusive.

Subtracting two `void*` pointers is ill-formed.  You probably meant to `reinterpret_cast<char*>` or something.  (Another sign that the code is very risky.)

> 5.7p4: For the purpose of these operators [binary `+` and `-`], a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.
>
> 5.7p6: When two pointers to elements of the same array are subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. ... Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: "You probably meant to reinterpret_cast<char*> or something" // Oops, yes. :)

Comment: "The sizeof operator gives information about the size of a complete object, not a subobject." // Aha! That makes sense. Add a smattering of standard quotes and I'll accept your answer. Thanks! :)